# Error spotting : For so many years (a)/ it is almost his habit (b)/ to go to the bed at 10 pm daily. (c)/ No error. (d)

Tags: exam-questions

> For so many years (a)/ it is almost his habit (b)/ to go to the bed at 10 pm daily. (c)/ No error. (d)

According to my book the correction to above sentence is to remove *the* before *bed* in part C but isn't the part B also wrong ? Correct form should be *it has been* as in part A we are given a period of time so doesn't it make sense to use present perfect here ?

Comment: That question has a number of things wrong with it.  "for so many years", "is", "almost his habit", "the bed".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Can you please elaborate how "for so many years" is wrong ?

Comment: There's very little that is right about that sentence.  **For so many years** does not go with **is**.  The verb would have to be changed to **was** or **has been**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo That makes part B wrong not part A. By your first comment I thought part a was also wrong.

Comment: Why should part A be allowed to stand?  That seems rather arbitrary.  Part A could be changed to "For years now", which would admit **is** or **has been** in part B.

Comment: What is the source of your example? It seems questionable at best.

Answer (score 1):

That question has a number of things wrong with it. "for so many years", "is", "almost his habit", "the bed".

For so many years does not go with is. The verb would have to be changed to was or has been. Part A could be changed to "For years now", which would admit is or has been in part B.

"Almost" does not go with "habit". There is no grammatical reason, just the meanings don't go well together. More likely would be to say "at almost 10pm"  (meaning just before 10pm)

Finally "bed" is one of those words (like "school") that we can use without an article. We say "go to bed" not "the bed".

> For many years it has been his habit to go to bed at almost 10 pm daily.